# How to send bitcoin to a multisig address

Tags: multi-signature

I am trying to deposit bitcoin to bitmex, which only offers multisig wallets.

I have tried to send from both GDAX and Jaxx, but the addresses are reported as invalid.

Apologies for the basic question, but how do I send to a multi-sig address?

Answer (score 1):

You send bitcoin to a multisig address in the same way as a normal address. Multisig addresses are just a type of P2SH address which start with a `3`, and have been supported by every major wallet and exchange for years.

If your address doesn't start with a `3`, it's probably not an address at all. (Unless it starts with `bc1` which is a very new address format and not widely supported yet)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you made a mistake copying the address. Addresses have a checksum in them that detects typos and that's how those wallets are able to tell that something is off. p2sh addresses are widely supported so the address type is not the problem here.

Note always use the copy/paste functionality of your OS when dealing with addresses. Alternatively, scan the QR code if you're using a mobile wallet. Don't go typing them in manually or you'll make mistakes.